# how to find out whether a number is the sum of a number and its digit's sum

Tags: c, loops, sum, long-integer

long integers **t** and **x** are input. **1 ≤ t ≤ 100 000** and **1 ≤ x ≤ 1 000 000**.

first, we take **t** from input and in the next **t** lines, we take **x** in each line. if there's any number **a** such that **x = a + sum-of-digits(a)**, print `Yes`. if not, print `No`.

e.g: input :

```
2
97
119
```

output:

```
No
Yes
```

in this example, `t = 2`.  so, we're given 2 numbers in the next lines. for `97`, there's no number **a** such that **97 = a + sum-of-digits(a)**. therefore, the output is `No`. but for **119**, **119 = 109 + 1 + 0 + 9** so **109** is a matching value of **a** and the output is `Yes`.

Here's my code but it doesn't run properly and I don't know why. can anyone figure out why it doesn't? or another idea for solving this question?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int t, x;
    scanf("%ld ", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld ", &x);
        unsigned int n = 1;
        while (n < 1000000)
        {
            long int r, count = 0, sum = 0;
            r = n;
            while (r > 0)
            {
                n = r % 10;
                sum += n;
                r /= 10;
                count++;
            }
            // sum = sum of digits of n
            if (x == (sum + x))
            {
                printf("Yes\n");
                break;
            }
        
            n++;
        }
        printf("No\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really want `n = r % 10;  sum += n;`?  That messes up `n`. Consider `sum += r % 10;` instead.

Comment: `if (x == (sum + x))` should be `if (x == (sum + n))` but see the comment above.

Comment: Also note that the sum of the digits can never be more than 54. So `n` doesn't need to start at 1.

Comment: chux and '109 identified a bug each. There's a third bug: You always print `No` immediately after printing `Yes`. To fix this, you could set a flag instead of printing `Yes`, then print either `Yes` or `No` based on the flag where you currently print `No`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 bugs in your code.

And as @chqrlie mentions in a comment: `i` and `n` should have type `long int`

So that the types are consistent.

See comments and fixes below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int t, x;
    scanf("%ld ", &t);
    for (long int i = 0; i < t; i++)  // Type change
    {
        scanf("%ld ", &x);
        long int n = 1;       // Type change
        while (n < 1000000)
        {
            long int r, count = 0, sum = 0;
            r = n;
            while (r > 0)
            {
                // n = r % 10; Bug: Overwriting n will mess up the loop
                // sum += n;
                long int tmp = r % 10; // Fix: Use another variable
                sum += tmp;            //      or directly do sum += r % 10

                r /= 10;
                count++;
            }
            // sum = sum of digits of n
            // if (x == (sum + x))     Bug: Simple typo
            if (x == (sum + n))    //  Fix: Use n
            {
                printf("Yes\n");
                break;
            }
        
            n++;
        }
        // printf("No\n");   Bug: Will always print after the while
        if (n == 1000000) printf("No\n"); // Fix: Only print when the while loop
                                          //      reached the maximum value for n
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Besides the bugs the variable `count` isn't used and there are performance problems, i.e. the `while` loop doesn't need to run to more than `x-1`. So try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int t, x;
    scanf("%ld ", &t);
    for (long int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld ", &x);
        long int n = 1;
        while (n < x)         // Performance improvement
        {
            long int r, sum = 0;
            r = n;
            while (r > 0)
            {
                sum += r % 10
                r /= 10;
            }
            if (x == (sum + n))
            {
                printf("Yes\n");
                break;
            }
        
            n++;
        }
        if (n == x) printf("No\n");   // Notice this change
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And you can do even better by noticing that the sum of digits can't be more than 54. The highest `x` value is 1000000 so 999999 will generate the highest possible digit sum, i.e. 6 * 9 = 54. In other words, for values of `x` above 54, you only need to check the 54 numbers before `x`. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int t, x;
    scanf("%ld ", &t);
    for (long int = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld ", &x);
        long int n = (x > 54) ? x - 54 : 1;  // Select start value
        while (n < x)
        {
            long int r, sum = 0;
            r = n;
            while (r > 0)
            {
                sum += r % 10
                r /= 10;
            }
            if (x == (sum + n))
            {
                printf("Yes\n");
                break;
            }
        
            n++;
        }
        if (n == x) printf("No\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` and `n` should have type `long int`

Comment: @chqrlie Nicely detected.  Best to use consistent types.

Comment: Interesting facts: the program prints `Yes` for 902214 numbers from 1 to 1000000, many of which 2 different matches (97740), close to the number of `No` (97786) but none with more than 2 matches.  For larger values of `x`, with appropriate code, the number of `No` and double matches both converge towards `9,0777777...%`. Experimental tests show a similar convergence for other bases toward a base-specific rational limit, but matches for more than 2 values of `a` for bases up to `7` and none for greater even bases. A formal analysis of this problem seems feasible...